# XML Transformation to Specific XML Schem

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a specific requirement to transform the XML report output to a specific format.

Below is the XML that needs to be transformed into the required output format. All employee IDs should be under one tag -

For Example: If I have 10 employee IDs, I want to show all the employees under the `enh:ExpensesBenefits` tag.

XML:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_Example"> 
    <wd:Report_Entry>     
       <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
       <wd:Employee_ID> 12346</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
       <wd:Employee_ID> 12347</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Required XML output Format-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/">
    <soap:Body>
        <enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
            <enh:SubmissionID>Sub01</enh:SubmissionID>
            <enh:Header>
                <enh:Version>5.4.0</enh:Version>
            </enh:Header>
            <enh:ExpensesBenefits>
                <enh:EmploymentID>12345</enh:EmploymentID>
            </enh:ExpensesBenefits>
        </enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: "I want to show all the employees under the enh:ExpensesBenefits tag." Your output shows only one?

Comment: XML transformations are usually done by using XSLT, ChatGPT can give you some hints or use Google Search, it has all been done before

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is XSLT based solution.

**XML**

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_Example">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>12346</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>12347</wd:Employee_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_Example"
                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                       xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/">
            <soap:Body>
                <enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
                    <enh:SubmissionID>Sub01</enh:SubmissionID>
                    <enh:Header>
                        <enh:Version>5.4.0</enh:Version>
                    </enh:Header>
                    <enh:ExpensesBenefits>
                        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
                            <enh:EmploymentID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
                            </enh:EmploymentID>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </enh:ExpensesBenefits>
                </enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/">
  <soap:Body>
    <enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
      <enh:SubmissionID>Sub01</enh:SubmissionID>
      <enh:Header>
        <enh:Version>5.4.0</enh:Version>
      </enh:Header>
      <enh:ExpensesBenefits>
        <enh:EmploymentID>12345</enh:EmploymentID>
        <enh:EmploymentID>12346</enh:EmploymentID>
        <enh:EmploymentID>12347</enh:EmploymentID>
      </enh:ExpensesBenefits>
    </enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -2):

Using a Powershell script with Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'
$submissionID = 'Sub01'
$version = '5.4.0'

$template = @"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/">
    <soap:Body>
        <enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
        </enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@

$inDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$outDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($template)

$envelope = $outDoc.Root
$enhNs = $envelope.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('enh')
$request = $outDoc.Descendants($enhNs + 'EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest').Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])[0]

$reportData = $inDoc.Root
$wdNs = $reportData.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('wd')
$ids = $inDoc.Descendants($wdNs + 'Employee_ID') | foreach{ $_.Value.Trim()}

$xSubmissionID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($enhNs + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('SubmissionID'), $submissionID)
$request.Add($xSubmissionID)

$header = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($enhNs + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Header'))

$version = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($enhNs + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Version'), $version)
$header.Add($version)

$request.Add($header)

$expensesBenefits = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($enhNs + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ExpensesBenefits'))
$request.Add($expensesBenefits)


foreach($id in $ids)
{
   $employee_ID = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($enhNs + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Employee_ID'), $id)
   $expensesBenefits.Add($employee_ID)
}

$outDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enh="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/paye-employers/err/v1/enhanced_reporting/">
  <soap:Body>
    <enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
      <enh:SubmissionID>Sub01</enh:SubmissionID>
      <enh:Header>
        <enh:Version>5.4.0</enh:Version>
      </enh:Header>
      <enh:ExpensesBenefits>
        <enh:Employee_ID>12345</enh:Employee_ID>
        <enh:Employee_ID>12346</enh:Employee_ID>
        <enh:Employee_ID>12347</enh:Employee_ID>
      </enh:ExpensesBenefits>
    </enh:EnhancedReportingSubmissionRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```